# Multiple condition declaration when checking for numerical zero - python

Tags: python, conditional-statements, zero, typechecking, or-operator

There's a question on [Idiomatic Python - checking for zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610416/idiomatic-python-checking-for-zero) but this question is consider with also checking the type of variables within the conditions.

Given the `0 if not variable else variable` style statement, it will let nully object slip through, e.g.

```
>>> x, y = None, []
>>> 0 if not(x and y) else x / y
0
>>> x, y = None, 0
>>> 0 if not(x and y) else x / y
0
>>> x, y = 0, 1
>>> 0 if not(x and y) else x / y
0
>>> x, y = 2, ""
>>> 0 if not(x and y) else x / y
0
>>> x, y = 2, 1
>>> 0 if not(x and y) else x / y
2
```

But if I explicitly check for variables' value to be zero, it will be somewhat better since it raises error when both types are different or types that cannot be compared to the zero value, e.g.:

```
>>> x, y = 2, ""
>>> 0 if (x&y) == 0 else x / y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'int' and 'str'
>>> x,y = "",""
>>> 0 if (x&y) == 0 else x / y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
>>> x,y = [],[]
>>> 0 if (x&y) == 0 else x / y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'list'
```

So normally when defining a condition to check for numerical value, **is something like the `0 if (x|y) == 0 else x/y` code more pythonic / more appropriate?**

But it's also problematic since it let's boolean type slip through and that causes some quite disturbing thing like `ZeroDivisionError` or `ValueError` to occur, e.g.:

```
>>> x,y = True, True
>>> 0 if (x&y) == 0 else x / y
1
>>> x,y = True, False
>>> 0 if (x&y) == 0 else x / y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>> x,y = False, True
>>> 0 if (x&y) == 0 else x / y
0
>>> x,y = False, True
>>> 0 if (x&y) == 0 else math.log(x/y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```

Also, this causes problem when types of variable are numerical but somewhat different:

```
>>> x, y = 1, 3.
>>> 0 if (x|y) == 0 else math.log(x/y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'int' and 'float'
```

And also the fact that the `_or` operator can't take float, it's weird:

```
>>> x, y = 1., 3.
>>> 0 if (x&y) == 0 and type(x) == type(y) == float else math.log(x/y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'float' and 'float'
>>> x, y = 1., 3.
>>> 0 if (x&y) == 0. and type(x) == type(y) == float else math.log(x/y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'float' and 'float'
>>> x, y = 1, 3
>>> 0 if (x&y) == 0 and type(x) == type(y) == float else math.log(x/y)
-1.0986122886681098
```

So the question is:

- **What is the pythonic way to check for multiple variable for the value zero?**
- Also, **it's important to not like boolean type slip and raise a error instead of letting it return zero, how can this be done?**
- And **how should the `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'float' and 'float'` be resolved for checking `(x|y) == 0` with x and y as float types?**

Comment: If you have numerical operations that depends on the exact type of both operands, the obvious (hence pythonic) solution is to either explicitely check the types of both operands or handle expected exceptions.

Comment: what about explicit check: "0 in (x,y)" ?

Comment: @A.Haaji this will fail on booleans : `0 in (True, False) => True`

Comment: Is there a difference between `0 in (x,y)` and `not (x and y)`?

Comment: How about `any(i is 0 for i in (x,y))` ?

Comment: @M4rtini: Using `is` on numbers is rarely a good idea. Also note that `0.0 is 0` evaluates to `False`, which is (probably) not what alvas wants.

Comment: @PM2Ring Good point, and using == would let boolean types pass through. 
`any(isinstance(i, numbers.Number) and i == 0 for i in (x,y))`  This may be good enough?  [ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441358/python-most-pythonic-way-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-number)

Comment: You know that `(x|y) == 0` is only true if both `x` and `y` equal `0`, right? Maybe you meant `x==0 or y==0`? Bear in mind that `|` is a bitwise operator, so it only makes sense to use it on ints (and booleans, which behave like ints), which is why it raises a `TypeError` if you try to use it with a float operand.

Comment: Yes, there's a difference between `0 in (x,y)` and `not (x and y)`, since the latter will evaluate to True if `x` or `y` is any False-y thing.

Comment: @PM2Ring Ah, it should have been `(x&y) == 0`!!

Comment: I don't understand why you want to combine these tests for zero into a single test, since zero in the numerator is quite different to zero in the denominator.  `x / 0` is undefined for any non-zero `x`, but `0 / 0` is _undetermined_, which is slightly different to undefined. And of course, `0 / y` is zero for any non-zero `y`.

Comment: That makes more sense. :) But with `x&y` you still get a TypeError if `x` or `y` is a float. Is that ok?

Comment: Nope, i'm checking for numerical types that's why I'm trying to look for some other solutions to check for types outside of `(x&y)`

Comment: Does anyone know whether there's a way to include some type hints to my variables? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/ , then checking for values would have by default checked for types.

Comment: Why not just use the [EAFP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11360858/4014959) approach, and perform your division in a `try:..except` block that catches `ZeroDivisionError` and `ValueError`, as suggested by Bruno?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)'s "Simple is better than complex" in mind, I would claim that if you want to check whether a value has a numeric type other than boolean (mind: Boolean *is* a numeric type in Python, and `1/True` is valid), the most pythonic way to do that is to do exactly that, explicitly, without any bitwise operations or relying on implicit checks.

```
import numbers

if not isinstance(y, numbers.Number) or type(y) is bool:
    raise TypeError("y must be a number")
return x / y if y else 0
```

Comment: Cool! Didn't know that `numbers` have some cool metas and classes!